Factor programming listener error for USE: and USING:
I tried below in factor listener
USE: ranges
No word named “ranges” found in current vocabulary search path
Same error for
USE: ranges ;
and
USING: ranges sequences ;
basically USE and USING does not work in listener.

It is math.ranges:
USE: math.ranges
3 10 [a,b]

=>
T{ range f 3 8 1 }

I found it with the help system, searching "ranges" shows a Vocabulary section that indicates "math.ranges".

It was renamed to ranges in Factor 0.99 released in August 2023.

the problem I was seeing was with the word USE and USING itself.
I re installed on mac and it started working .Not sure was related to directory permissions.
